# Managing Service in fragments/tab application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-fragments

I have three tabs in app and three fragments each and I want to start the Service as my app is started but I want to update only my one of the fragment ,Please give me the idea how to do this, when to start the Service and how to put the broadcast receiver to update the fragment so that fragment get updated when its containing tab is even not open? Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is the third time that you have deleted and re-asked the same question within the past few hours. This is inappropriate behavior for StackOverflow.

Comment: no 2nd time and I have changed my whole question @CommonsWare

Comment: Why did't you just edit your question? I dont see any difference. I answered on your deleted version, so if you dont want answers, dont ask!

Comment: sorry i did'nt know here you can edit whole question aswell, am new here @electrofant

Comment: Next time you know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the receiver in your own Fragment which you want to update. Fragment has the similar life cicyle with Activity.